# Object delete and return property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there any quick way in JS to remove *and return* an object property?

```
const objectA = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const b = object.doSomething("b");
const objectB = { b };

objectA is now { a: 1 }
objectB is { b: 2 }
```

I know I could assign the property and then delete it, but I was wondering if there was any way in JS to do it in one function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for this operation. You need to do it manually; here is a way:

```js
function doSomething(source, ...keys) {
  var result = keys.reduce((r, k) => {
    r[k] = source[k];
    delete source[k];
    return r;
  }, {});

  return result;
}

var obj1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj2 = doSomething(obj1, 'b');

console.log(obj1, obj2);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:  No, there is no single function that does all of that.

But you can do something like this:

```
const objectB = {};
const k = 'b'; 

let t;

objectB[k] = t = objectA[k] && delete objectA[k] && t;
```

You could wrap this into a function like this:

```
function deleteReturn(object, key) {
    let temp;

    return (temp = object[key]) && delete object[key] && temp;
}

const b = deleteReturn(objectA, 'b');

const objectB = { b };
```

If you want to make it more maintainable, you should break the one-liner into multiple statements.